# racket at-exp include curly bracket

Tags: racket

How can I use at-exp to include blew raw string:

```
package foo

}

import (
```

I write like this, but it cannot include the "}" character:

```
#lang at-exp racket/base

    (define code @S{
        package foo

        }

        import (
    }
```

How to include special character like "{}" in the raw part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@S|{...}|` for that: since the closing part is `}|`, plain `}`s would not be special.  Also, remember to use `|@` instead of just `@` for nested forms.  And if you need another different quotation since you want to use `}|`s too, you can add more things between, as in `@S|==={...}===|`.  See the [documentation page](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader.html) for details (look for `|{`s, and see [section 2.4.1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader.html#%28part._alt-body-syntax%29)).

As for what you've found: this is not the same.  What you're doing there is a nested `"{"` string, which you can use for each unbalanced character.  But that is much less convenient than the above alternative quotation syntax.

Comment: If Eli's answer works, then you should accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

oh, sorry, I find use @|"{"| is ok.